# From my web.xml file, how can I gain access to my webapp name?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat

For instance, under tomcat, my webapp name is the same as the war file. But this can be renamed at any time and redeployed, so I'd like to access the webapp name inside my web.xml, specifically to set the webappRootkey for log4j and Spring under tomcat.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [retrieve the `<display-name/>` element programmatically](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) in a web app with

```
ServletContext.getServletContextName()
```

Within the spring context however, you can get same (Spring 3.x) using the same `ServletContext` object as

```
value="#{servletContext.servletContextName}
```